# Draw with ImageMagick on Rails not working with PNG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, watermark

I'm trying to add a watermark on images in a Rails app. It works when the watermark is a JPG but not when it's a PNG.

```
<% @photo = photo.variant(
  combine_options: {
    gravity: 'center',
    resize: '770x578',
    draw: 'image Over 0,0 0,0 "' + Property::WATERMARK_PATH.to_s + '"'
  }
) %>
```

In the model:

```
WATERMARK_PATH = Rails.root.join('app','assets', 'images', 'watermark.png')
```

Can anyone tell me why that's happening and how to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have libpng installed as a delegate in your ImageMagick. `convert version` should list png. If not, then you do not have png inststalled. Sorry, I do not know Rails. Also do you have a correct path to your PNG image?

Comment: Please make a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I looked at the gems `image_magick`, `rmagick`, and `mini_magick` and none of them have a method `variant`. What kind of object is `photo`? What gem are you using?